# HTTP error when uploading images in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am using xampp in windows 7. Whenever I try to upload media files, I get `HTTP error`.

I have  tried following solutions, but sill getting same error.

- `upload_max_filesize=200M`
- `memory_limit = 512M`
- `post_max_size=200MB`in php.ini.
- `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` in wp-config.php

I have changed permission also, but still same error.

Comment: Can you please provide the error that you are getting? Looking specifically for HTTP Error Code.

Comment: It just shows HTTP Error. How do i get error code?

Comment: Try to use Chrome / Firefox Developer Tools / Firebug and try to see if Fiddler helps. Need HTTP Error / Status Code to diagnose the issue.

Comment: POST http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/async-upload.php 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: If you are in a linux system check the chmod of the destination folder

Answer (score 1):

I figured out myself.
I used

> 200MB
>   instead of 
>   **200M**
>   because of that server default post_max_size became 200bytes.